# Multiple if condition in elixir

Tags: elixir

How can I implement multiple if conditions in my code like below

```
person = %Person{}

if x.name == "Test" do 
  person = %{person | name: "Test"}
end

if x.age == 50 do 
 person = %{person | age: 50}
end
```

here "x" is another object where I am trying to validate data and then updating person struct accordingly. 
I already wrote code as above but got a below warning

> the variable "person" is unsafe as it has been set inside one of:
>   case, cond, receive, if, and, or, &&, ||. Please explicitly return the
>   variable value instead. For example:
>
> ```
> case integer do
>   1 -> atom = :one
>   2 -> atom = :two
> end
> ```
>
> should be written as
>
> ```
> atom =
>   case integer do
>     1 -> :one
>     2 -> :two
>   end
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are matching multiple clauses to validate a field, I would combine functions that validate the pieces, as follows:

```
defmodule PersonChecker do
  def validate(x, person) do
    person
    |> validate_name(x)
    |> validate_age(x)
  end

  defp validate_name(person, %{name: name}) when name == "Test" do
    %{person | name: "Test"}
  end
  defp validate_name(person, _x), do: person

  defp validate_age(person, %{age: age}) when age == 50 do
    %{person | age: 50}
  end
  defp validate_age(_x, person), do: person
end
```

If you wanted to use `case` instead of multiple `validate_name` functions it would look like this:

```
defp validate_name(person, x) do
  case x.name do
    "Test" -> %{person | name: "Test"}
    _ -> person
  end
end
```

As an aside, depending on your use case, it might be easier to muck with `x` to strip out the fields you don't want, and then convert `x` into a struct using the `struct(Person, x)` function.

Answer (score 2):

You can't rebind the variable inside the block. As the error message suggest, set it explicit:

```
person = %Person{}
person = if x.name == "Test", do: %{person | name: "Test"}, else: person
person = if x.age == 50, do: %{person | age: 50}, else: person
```

Even if variables are immutable, Elixir allows rebinding, but it would be easier to understand if it would not be allowed (like in Erlang). In this case, you would have to write something like:

```
person = %Person{}
person_with_name = if x.name == "Test", do: %{person | name: "Test"}, else: person
person_with_name_and_age = if x.age == 50, do: %{person_with_name | age: 50}, else: person_with_name
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything in Elixir is immutable. I would suggest you to read [this great writing by José Valim](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2016/01/comparing-elixir-and-erlang-variables/) on rebinding variables in Elixir.

The functionality you are after looks mostly as a reducing the `struct` on a list of fields, that’s why I probably would go with [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3):

```rb
defmodule Person, do: defstruct ~w|foo name age|a
x = [name: true, age: false] # flags

~w|name age|a
|> Enum.zip(['Test', 50])
|> Enum.reduce(%Person{foo: :bar}, fn {field, value}, acc ->
     if x[field], do: %{acc | field => value}, else: acc
   end)
#⇒ %Person{age: nil, foo: :bar, name: 'Test'}
```